# Data Structure for keeping time and day of the week PHP

Tags: php, data-structures, dayofweek

How can I hold in a data structure in PHP only the time of the day and the day of the week?

E.g.: 17:20 Sunday

Also I need to add minutes and hours to it.

E.g.: 22:03 Sunday + 03:00 = 01:03 Monday

Comment: You start by reading the manual. Here's "one" of them http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Probaly the best way for this is to create a custom class

Comment: I was able to recreate both of these cases in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) (an  online PHP editor) in a little over 6 minutes using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Visit those links and give it a try in PHPFiddle. If you're still having trouble, post what you've tried and I'm sure people will be glad to help. According to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) SO, usually addresses _"a specific programming problem"_. This question, in it's current form, is a little too broad.

Comment: Well it was for a friend so i can't futher provide info unless I get some more from them...

Comment: @RaduStanescu True, but again, you could visit the links and recreate the examples above using `date()`, `time()` and `strtotime()`. The documentation on these functions is exceptional. If you're able to recreate the examples then you'll be able to assist your friend.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Untested and probably not the best way

```
class TimeWeekday {
    private $hour;
    private $minute;
    private $day;

    private $days = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');

    public function __construct($hour, $minute, $day) {
        $this->hour = $hour;
        $this->minute = $minute;
        $this->day = $day;
    }

    public function add($hours, $minutes, $days = 0) {
        $newMinutes = $this->minute + $minutes;
        $this->minute = $newMinutes % 60;
        if ($this->minute < 0) {
            $this->minute += 60;
        }
        $newHours = $this->hour + $hours + floor($newMinutes / 60);
        $this->hour = $newHours % 24;
        if ($this->hour < 0) {
            $this->hour += 24;
        }
        $newDay = $this->day + $days + floor($newHours / 60);
        $this->day = $newDay % 7;
        if ($this->day < 0) {
            $this->day += 7;
        }
    }

    public function substract($hours, $minurtes, $days = 0) {
        $this->add(-$hours, -$minurtes, -$days);
    }

    public function getValue() {
        return sprintf('%02d:%02d %s', $this->hour, $this->minute, $this->days[$this->day]);
    }
}
```

.

```
$x = new TimeWeekday(22, 3, 6);
$x->add(3,0);
echo $x->getValue();
```